# Xcode push to multiple git remotes

Tags: xcode, git

I've configured multiple remotes for push like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/5597821. But it seems that Xcode pushes only at one of them. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Xcode Push to Multiple Git Remotes?](https://dzone.com/articles/xcode-push-to-multiple-git-remotes-learn-ios-dev-b) ":

> Believe me, I had spent almost two weeks trying to figure out if one of the hacks above could work with Xcode from the GUI. Alas, without any success.
>   For me it seems Xcode is using a perl script as an intermediary between the GUI and the commands, but I couldn’t manage to break it.
>
> It is quite frustrating, but at the time of writing the only way to push to multiple remotes with one command is only available from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I saw this article, but I hope that someone else solved this problem.